# How to destroy all cookies from index.php by using session_destroy using php?

Tags: php

Here is my logout.php file.Here i tried to destroy all the session when the href link is selected.
But my section is not get destroyed when i use the following line in my php file.
How can i use the destroy session when href is selected?

*logout.php*

```
<?php
<div>
 <span style="font-size: 190%"><?php  echo ("Please")?> <?php session_start();session_unset();session_destroy();session_write_close();header('Location:index.php');die; echo '<a href="index.php"> login</a>' ?></a><?php echo(" back to the page") ?><br /><br /></span>
</div>
?>
```

Comment: That code is getting executed every time this page loads, not just when clicking the link.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` and `header()` must be called before any output is sent.

> Note:
>   To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate logout.php page and destroy session there.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:index.php');
```

and just link to it